# How do you expose a Grails domain model using OData?

Tags: grails, jpa, jax-rs, odata

Ideally there would be a plugin that automatically exposed the Grails domain model as OData but I can't see one.

There is OData4j which will let you expose POJOs or JPA as OData however it uses JAX-RS and Jersey under the covers and I'm not sure how to use that inside a Grails application.

Comment: i thought about that some time ago, and i think that there is no native support for odata, because there is already support for alternatives like HAL and Atom (see the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/webServices.html#hypermedia)). But if anyone has more information, i would looking forward to hear about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Apache Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/). Follow their [Java example](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/read/tutorial_read.html#431-create-and-implement-the-servlet) and modify for Groovy/Grails like such:

```
class DataController {
    def action() {
        // create odata handler and configure it with DemoEdmProvider and Processor
        def odata = OData.newInstance()
        def edm = odata.createServiceMetadata(new DemoEdmProvider(), [])
        def handler = odata.createHandler(edm)
        handler.register(new DemoEntityCollectionProcessor())

        // let the handler do the work
        handler.process(request, response)
        return false
    }
}
```